How can I resolve an error that appeared in machine learning using cnn and lstm?
I would like to create a regression model with 6 time-series images as explanatory variables and 3 output layers. At the moment, there are 125 pairs of explanatory variables (6 time-series images) and objective variables (3 numerical values). The 6 images with time-series relationships are grouped in a folder. I have created the model with the following code The execution environment is Google colab.
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cv2
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import ConvLSTM2D, BatchNormalization, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf


# Three types of numerical data
df = pd.read_excel(r"/path/to/file/hoge.xlsx")

# Image data loading and preprocessing
image_folder = r"/path/to/folder"
images = []
labels = []

img_set_cnt = 125
min_img_cnt = 6

for i in range(1, img_set_cnt + 1):
    lst = []
    for j in range(1, min_img_cnt + 1):
        img_path = os.path.join(image_folder, str(i), f"no{i}_BW_{j}.jpg")
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        img = np.array(img) / 255.0  # normalization (e.g. in floating-point representation system)
        lst.append(img)
    images.append(lst)
    labels.append(df.iloc[i-1][["column1", "column2", "column3"]].values)

labels = np.array(labels)

# Split data into training and testing
train_x, val_x, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=71, shuffle=True)

# Input specification is only required on the first layer
model = Sequential([
    ConvLSTM2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(18,18), return_sequences=True, data_format="channels_last", input_shape=(min_img_cnt, 256, 256, 1)),
    BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8),
    ConvLSTM2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(18,18), return_sequences=True, data_format="channels_last"),
    BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8),
    ConvLSTM2D(filters=3, kernel_size=(6,6), return_sequences=False, data_format="channels_last", activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=3, activation='linear')  # Assume identity function for regression
])


print(len(images))  # Number of image sets
print(len(images[0]))  # Number of images in the first image set
print(images[0][0].shape)  # Shape of the first image in the first image set


# Model Compilation
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['mae']) 

# Model Learning
history = model.fit(
    np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y),
    batch_size=16, 
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=(np.array(val_x), np.array(val_y)),
    shuffle=True)


#############Execution Result#############
125
6
(256, 256)
Epoch 1/10

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 5>()
history = model.fit(
    np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), 
    batch_size=16, 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
try:
    ctx.ensure_initialized()
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
                                      inputs, attrs, num_outputs)

except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error
##########################################
I don't know why the word Graph is in error when doing machine learning. Please tell me what to do.
